# Most performant way to do document wide PNG animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, png

I've got a GIF animation that I use thoughout my site as a saving/loading icon: [image: Loader icon]

Because of edges on different background colors, I'd like to change it to a PNG animation.

When I want to show a loader at this moment I only have to make sure the following span is visible:

`<span class="loader"></span>`

There are several ways how this span be inserted in the document: through knockout visible binding, through JS, only by stylesheets etc.

**Problem**

*I don't want my animation code to be aware of **how** this span ended up visible on the document, I just want him to animate it.*

Of course scanning the whole document every frame (16 fps) for potential new spans with the 'loader' class, **just** to know which position properties need to be animated is not quite performant.

So what would be a good performant way to do a document wide png animation?

Note that I do need to support IE8 :(

Comment: I was reading through all of that, thinking up solutions of how you could achieve this purely with CSS. Then you threw that IE8 kicker in at the end! :(

Comment: haha yeah sorry that's my saddistic soul

Answer (score 1):

Using a sprite in combination with CSS `background-position` comes immediately to mind:
[image]  (yes I know it's a pretty shitty one, but it'll do the job).

You mentioned Knockout, and as its aim is to separate logic from presentation, I'll use that. However, there's no way to *completely*  separate it that I know of that doesn't come with a performance cost (cf your comment). Typically in Knockout `bindingHandlers` are used to do DOM manip independently of your viewModel.

Haven't tested, but should normally work on IE8. Run the snippet below for a demo

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.loadIndicator = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    if (val == true) {
      var intv = setInterval(function() {
        var bgX = parseInt(element.style.backgroundPosition.split(' ')[0].replace('px',''));
        if (bgX > -48) // 4 frames of 14px
          element.style.backgroundPosition = (bgX - 14) + 'px';
        else 
          element.style.backgroundPosition = '0px';
      }, 150);
      element.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
      clearInterval(intv);
    }
  }
};
var app = { loading: ko.observable(true) };
ko.applyBindings(app);
// simulate 'loaded' after 3 secs
setTimeout(function() { app.loading(false); }, 3000);
```

```css
.loader {
   display: block;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/1OZACw8.png);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span class="loader" data-bind="loadIndicator: loading"></span>
```

If you think a custom binding is not worth it, you can use the `visible` binding in combination with a **transparent animated GIF** (yes, it is possible). See for example: http://blog.ciuly.com/general/internet/making-animated-gif-transparent-with-gimp/. 
Any way you choose, you'll have to keep track of whether something has finished loading/ saving, for example in a KO observable property.

Prefer not using Knockout? You could do the same in vanilla JS/ jQuery. However, because you have to track the status from somewhere, you have to either interval-check DOM attributes (which achieves the same as Knockout does automatically on observables) or choose a variant of the approach below where you call an `init`/ `stop` function to hide/display the loader.

```js
function loader(container) {
  var elem = document.createElement('span');
  elem.className = 'loader';
  container.appendChild(elem);

  var intv = setInterval(function() {
    var bgX = parseInt(elem.style.backgroundPosition.split(' ')[0].replace('px',''));
    if (bgX > -48) // 4 frames of 14px
      elem.style.backgroundPosition = (bgX - 14) + 'px';
    else 
      elem.style.backgroundPosition = '0px';
  }, 150);

  this.stop = function() { 
    clearInterval(intv);
    container.removeChild(elem);
  };
}
var x = new loader(document.body);
setTimeout(function() { x.stop() }, 10000);
```

Performance-wise I believe the animated transparent GIF with `visible` binding and the vanilla `init/stop` method are the 2 best candidates.

Comment: Hi Tyblitz, thanks for your very eloborate answer. I think I was a bit unclear in my question though. For me it's very important to separate the part that is animating the image, and the part that is adding or showing the `loader`. Like with a GIF. You just don't want to think about how it ended up at your screen, just that it animates.

Comment: @DirkBoer Ah, I was focusing more on the 'I want to make it a non-costly, compatible PNG animation' part. So you actually want to separate logic from presentation, & since you're using Knockout, that would be easy with a component/ custom binding/ viewmodel property. If I find the time & courage I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi Tyblitz, yeah I realise that my question might not be that clear. Maybe I also want to much: I actually also want to separate the presentation from knockout :| if that's possible..actually just like the current implementation with a GIF. 
Span with Loader class visible? -> show the png animation.

Comment: Sorry, I am aware that I might be too much of a purist in this case :)

Comment: @DirkBoer I have updated my answer with all possible ways to achieve what you wish to. I'm also a bit of a purist, but I think having the logic inside a binding/ making a clear distinction between JS objects meant for DOM manip & those meant for data manip is enough 'separated'.